# Conflicted foreign key sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.UserProfile_dbo.UserWork_UserWorkId". The conflict occurred in
>   database "aspnet-UserAndWork-20130222085848", table "dbo.UserWork",
>   column 'UserWorkId'.
>       The statement has been terminated.

I run into the error message while loading the page
Here are two of my tables classes

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId{get;set;}
    public string Username{get;set;}
    public int UserWorkId{get;set;}
    [foreignkey("UserWorkId")]
    public virtual UserWork UserWorkLog{get;set;}
}

public class UserWork
{
    [Key]
    public int UserWorkId{get;set;}
    public int UserId;
    //somemoire
}
```

Comment: Apparently you are trying to save `UserProfile` instance with nonexistent reference to the `UserWork`. How is you saving done in code?

Comment: check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965837/insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint

Comment: shouldnt this line "[foreignkey("UserWorkId")]" above "public int UserWorkId{get;set;}" ?