# Insert statement error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table `dbo.Students_Old` with columns :

> Name(varchar), DocNum(int),  Group(varchar),  Form(varchar).

It have no primary key and I need to normalize this table. So I am going to make three tables:

> dbo.Students(StudentId(int primary key), Name(varchar), Group(int fk),
>   Form(int fk),
>
> dbo.Forms(FormId(int pk), FName(varchar)), dbo.Groups(GroupId(int pk),
>   GName(varchar)).

And also I need to fill all this tables with data from `dbo.Students_Old`. My code is:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Groups(GroupId int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, GName nvarchar(10));

GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Groups(GName) 
  select Group
  from dbo.Students_Old
  group by Group

GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Forms(FormId int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, Form nvarchar(20));

INSERT INTO dbo.Forms(Form) 
select Form
from dbo.Students_Old
group by Form

GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Students (StudentId int PRIMARY KEY, Name nvarchar(50),
Form int NOT NULL,
Group int NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT Form FOREIGN KEY(StudentId) REFERENCES dbo.Forms(FormId),
 CONSTRAINT Grup FOREIGN KEY(StudentId) REFERENCES dbo.Groups(GroupId));

GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Students(StudentId, Name, Form, Group) 
select DocNum, Name, f.FormId, g.GroupId 
from dbo.Students_Old s
join dbo.Forms f on s.Form=f.Form
join dbo.Groups g on s.Group=g.GName
```

Also Students_Old.DocNum is unique.

Tables creates normaly, but on the insert statement i have an error:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "Form". The conflict occurred in database "DBNames", table "dbo.Forms", column 'FormId'.
```

Help me please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965837/insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint

Comment: Yes, but I have those values in table.

Comment: Did you really mean to have `StudentID` as a FK to `Forms` and `Groups`? Your text says you should have two other columns in `Student` that is FK to `Forms` and `Groups`.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson, yes, but what shuld I do?

Comment: How about having two columns in `Student`  `FormID` that is a FK to `Forms` and `GroupId` that is a FK to `Groups`? That is what you described in your text but it is not what your code says.

Comment: `CONSTRAINT Form FOREIGN KEY(FormId) REFERENCES dbo.Forms(FormId),
 CONSTRAINT Grup FOREIGN KEY(GroupId) REFERENCES dbo.Groups(GroupId));`

Comment: He is already having those columns for foreign key, only their names are Form and Group (both int type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the below query on a new database

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Groups(GroupId int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, GName nvarchar(10));

GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Groups(GName) 
  select Group
  from dbo.Students_Old
  group by Group

GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Forms(FormId int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, Form nvarchar(20));

INSERT INTO dbo.Forms(Form) 
select Form
from dbo.Students_Old
group by Form

GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Students (StudentId int PRIMARY KEY, Name nvarchar(50),
Form int NOT NULL,
[Group] int NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT Form FOREIGN KEY(Form) REFERENCES dbo.Forms(FormId),
 CONSTRAINT Grup FOREIGN KEY(Group) REFERENCES dbo.Groups(GroupId));

GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Students(StudentId, Name, Form, Group) 
select DocNum, Name, f.FormId, g.GroupId 
from dbo.Students_Old s
join dbo.Forms f on s.Form=f.Form
join dbo.Groups g on s.Group=g.GName
```

I've changed to following lines

```
 CONSTRAINT Form FOREIGN KEY(Form) REFERENCES dbo.Forms(FormId),
 CONSTRAINT Grup FOREIGN KEY([Group]) REFERENCES dbo.Groups(GroupId));
```

In your code the foreign key is made on `StudentID` column

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that is the case, since you get the  FOREIGN KEY  error, but try avoiding column names like GROUP or other reserved words. While you can avoid errors on table creation step, you can face serious problems during modifications/updates on such tables.

Answer (score 0):

execute below query.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Groups(GroupId int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, GName nvarchar(10));

GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Groups(GName) 
  select [Group]
  from dbo.Students_Old
  group by [Group]

GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Forms(FormId int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, Form nvarchar(20));

INSERT INTO dbo.Forms(Form) 
select Form
from dbo.Students_Old
group by Form

GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Students (StudentId int PRIMARY KEY, Name nvarchar(50),
Form int NOT NULL,
[Group] int NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT Form FOREIGN KEY(StudentId) REFERENCES dbo.Forms(FormId),
 CONSTRAINT Grup FOREIGN KEY(StudentId) REFERENCES dbo.Groups(GroupId));

GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Students(StudentId, Name, Form, [Group]) 
select DocNum, Name, f.FormId, g.GroupId 
from dbo.Students_Old s
join dbo.Forms f on s.Form=f.Form
join dbo.Groups g on s.[Group]=g.GName
```