# I am insert one table ERP_GatePass but ERP_GatePass_old table will be Refer,So mthis Error Occur

Tags: asp.net

The `INSERT` statement conflicted with the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint `"FK_ERP_AssetIssue_ERP_GatePass".` The conflict occurred in database `"ERP_ASSETS_NFA"`, table `"dbo.ERP_GatePass_Old"`, column `'GPID'`.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965837/insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint)

Answer (score 0):

In your table dbo.ERP_GatePass, it has a foreign key reference to another table. The  FK works is it cannot have a value in that column that is not also in the primary key column of the referenced table.

You can Rectify or findout using this following way [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965837/insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint#2965837%202965837)

Comment: @Ananda Somewhere you are sending a value as `0` that has foreign key relation with the primary key column