# How to insert record in a many to many relationship junction table

Tags: sql-server, many-to-many, sql-insert

Okay so i have the following many to many relationship in 3 tables:

```
**MEAL**
mealID

**FoodProduct**
fpID

**meal_food**
mealID
fpID
quantity
```

The **MEAL** and **FoodProduct** tables are already populated so i just need to select a `mealID` and a `fpID` and manually set a `quantity`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How have you added records to MEAL and FoodProduct?

Comment: are you using ado.net or EF for DB operations

Comment: What's wrong with a simple insert into? This is very basic sql....

Comment: insert into meal_food(mealID,fpID,quantity) values (1,1,5)

Comment: The MEAL and FoodProduct do have records already.And yes i am using .NET Windows Forms.  Using INSERT INTO meal_aliment (mealID,alimentID,gramage) VALUES ('1','2','0') generates the following error : {"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK__meal_alim__alime__145C0A3F\". The conflict occurred in database \"FoodDBTEST\", table \"dbo.aliment\", column 'alimentID'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Comment: You can only insert values corresponding to the values you already have in the related tables. That's the point of foreign keys.

Comment: So, is this post just another dupe of the many [INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965837/insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint) questions?

Comment: Indeed it is i solved it thank you all.