# Another The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint error with drop down list

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have one table [Software] and have 2 foreign key [Brand_ID,Category_ID]. I have bonded the 2 table [Brand and Category] with a drop down list.

When the insert statement is executing I am getting the `INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint` error.

Here is the code:

```
Insert INTO tblSoftware(Description,Date_Of_Purchase,Price,Brand_ID,Category_ID) Values (@Description,@Date_Of_Purchase,@Price,@Brand_ID,@Category_ID)", con);
```

When I remove the Brand_ID and Category_ID from the sql statement, it is inserting fine.

How do i solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Without the table definitions and the values attempting to be inserted this is not really an answerable question. But this has been answered dozens and dozens of times....even in the title you realize this has been answered before.

Comment: Are the values of @Brand_ID,@Category_ID existing into parent tables ?

Comment: values of @Brand_ID,@Category_ID are existing parent tables then only we can't insert data into table because of having referential integrity

Comment: Try searching next time, there are at least six answered questions regarding this error on SO alone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965837/insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint)

Answer (score 1):

@nexusmusic00, make sure when you execute insert statement at that time Brand_ID and Category_ID values exists in Brand and Category table respectively.

Comment: values exist in both tables.

Comment: Kindly note there is no need for mentioning the OP at your answer. regards.

Answer (score 0):

What you are passing for @Brand_ID,@Category_ID when user did not select any thing from dropdown. I guess you are passing 0 for those two parameters that cause issue you have to set that value as NULL.