# SP insert error : Conflict with foreign Key

Tags: sql, asp.net, stored-procedures

I know there are several questions related to this, but I trued them it did not work.

I have an sp to insert datas into a table, the table has foreign keys as well.

This is the structure of my table that I want to insert,

[image]

Iam using asp.net and my sp looks like below

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertJob]
@CompanyID INT,
@DepartmentID INT,
@No VARCHAR(50),
@Date DATETIME,
@CustomerID INT,
@JobTypeID INT,
@BillNo VARCHAR(50),
@GoodsType VARCHAR(50),
@Remarks VARCHAR(250),
@Cancelled BIT,
@CancelledRemarks VARCHAR(50),
@UserId INT,
@Closed BIT,
@Shipper VARCHAR(100),
@SupplierInvoice VARCHAR(50),
@HBillNo VARCHAR(50),
@JobStartedDate DATETIME,
@AssignedStaffid INT,
@VesselorFlightName VARCHAR(100),
@VesselorFlightArvDate DATETIME,
@FormNumber VARCHAR(50),
@FinancialId INT,
@NoofPackages INT,
@TypeOfPackages VARCHAR(100),
@ChargableWeight VARCHAR(50),
@Volume VARCHAR(50),
@DispatchMode VARCHAR(500),
@TransactionId INT OUT,
    @TransactionNo NVARCHAR(50) OUT

AS
BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON;
     DECLARE @Id AS INT
       SELECT @Id=isnull(max(Id),0)+1 FROM  Job

 INSERT INTO Job( Id, CompanyID, DepartmentID, No, Date, CustomerID, JobTypeID, BillNo, GoodsType, Remarks, Cancelled, CancelledRemarks, UserId, Closed, Shipper, SupplierInvoiceNo, HBillNo, JobStartedDate, AssignedStaffid, VesselorFlightName, VesselorFlightArvDate, FormNumber,  NoOfPackages, TypeOfPackages, ChargableWeight, Volume, DispatchMode) 

values(@Id,@CompanyID,@DepartmentID,@No,@Date,@CustomerID,@JobTypeID,@BillNo,@GoodsType,@Remarks,@Cancelled,@CancelledRemarks,@UserId,@Closed,@Shipper,@SupplierInvoice,@HBillNo,@JobStartedDate,@AssignedStaffid,@VesselorFlightName,@VesselorFlightArvDate,   @FormNumber,@NoofPackages, @TypeOfPackages, @ChargableWeight, @Volume, @DispatchMode)

SELECT @TransactionId = @Id
SELECT @TransactionNo = @No 
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END
```

I got error

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Job_JobType". The conflict occurred in database "*dbname*", table "dbo.JobType".
>   The statement has been terminated.

this is my JobType table

[image]

so I tried to insert like this and error remains

```
INSERT INTO Job (Id,CompanyID,DepartmentID,No,Date,CustomerID,JobTypeID,BillNo,GoodsType,Remarks,Cancelled,CancelledRemarks,UserId,Closed,Shipper,SupplierInvoiceNo,HBillNo,JobStartedDate,AssignedStaffid,VesselorFlightName,VesselorFlightArvDate,FormNumber,NoOfPackages,TypeOfPackages,ChargableWeight,Volume,DispatchMode)

VALUES (88,1,0,'test',2018-01-01,13,1,3246,'','',0,'',2,0,'','',234632,2018-01-01,1,'test',2018-01-01,'',1,0,'','0','');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965837/insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: What's the value of `@JobTypeID`, and does it exist in `dbo.JobType` (I'm assuming the FK relationship, can you show the FK?)

Comment: The value of `JobTypeID` of `1` does not exist in the `JobType` table.

Comment: it is a foreign key constraint, May be you are inserting  a value for job_id which is not present in Parent table.

Comment: added my jobtype table data and you can see 1 is there

Comment: Doe the relationship include CompanyID and DepartmentID?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965837/insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint

check this link if it helps

Answer (score 0):

In your insert query, the JobTypeID is being inserted as ''. If it is a foreign key, you cannot insert a '' into it. Enter a valid Id into it

Comment: I am inserting 1 not "