# Adding values to database but foreign key constraint failed

Tags: sqlite

I'm new to sqlite3 and I'm not so knowledgeable about foreign keys. I was trying to insert a data to User:

insert into `User`(`User_id`, `name`) values(201503426, 'John Doe');

But after I run it, I got `foreign key constraint failed` message.

So I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `User` (
`User_id`   integer,
`plate_number`  integer DEFAULT 0,
`name`  text DEFAULT 'user',
`spot_number`   integer DEFAULT 0,
`credit`    integer DEFAULT 0,
`order_id`  integer DEFAULT 0,
FOREIGN KEY(`order_id`) REFERENCES `Orderr`(`order_id`),
FOREIGN KEY(`spot_number`) REFERENCES `Spot`(`spot_id`),
PRIMARY KEY(`User_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Spot` (
`spot_id`   integer,
`user_id`   text DEFAULT 'vacant',
`order_id`  integer DEFAULT 0,
`status`    integer DEFAULT 0,
FOREIGN KEY(`order_id`) REFERENCES `Orderr`(`order_id`),
FOREIGN KEY(`user_id`) REFERENCES `User`(`User_id`),
PRIMARY KEY(`spot_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Orderr` (
`order_id`  integer,
`user_id`   text DEFAULT 'user',
`spot_number`   integer DEFAULT 0,
`amount_due`    integer DEFAULT 0,
`time_lapse`    integer DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY(`order_id`),
FOREIGN KEY(`user_id`) REFERENCES `User`(`User_id`),
FOREIGN KEY(`spot_number`) REFERENCES `Spot`(`spot_id`)
);
```

How can I add the values without getting an error?.

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965837/insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint-sql-server, and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46410/how-do-i-insert-a-row-which-contains-a-foreign-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your `User` table:

```
CREATE TABLE User (
    User_id integer,
    plate_number integer DEFAULT 0,
    name text DEFAULT 'user',
    spot_number integer DEFAULT 0,
    credit integer DEFAULT 0,
    order_id integer DEFAULT 0,
    FOREIGN KEY(order_id) REFERENCES Orderr(order_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(spot_number) REFERENCES Spot(spot_id),
    PRIMARY KEY(User_id)
);
```

Of importance here, for all columns other than `User_id`, you have default non `NULL` values defined.  Now consider your insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO User (User_id, name)
VALUES
    (201503426, 'John Doe');
```

Because you did not specify the `order_id` column (as well as several others), therefore the *default* value will be inserted.  So, your insert would result in the following record being added:

```
(User_id,   plate_number, name,       spot_number, credit, order_id)
(201503426, 0,            'John Doe', 0,           0,      0)
```

Now, because you have foreign key constraints in place on `order_id` and `spot_number`, SQLite will check to make sure that those corresponding tables actually have entires corresponding to the record you inserted.  My guess is that such records do *not* exist, which is why you are seeing this error.

There are several ways to fix this, but the immediate change I would suggest would be to *not* use default values for your foreign key columns.  Instead, allow them to be `NULL`.  This way, you may do your current insert, and instead you would end up with the following record:

```
(User_id,   plate_number, name,       spot_number, credit, order_id)
(201503426, NULL,         'John Doe', NULL,        NULL,   NULL)
```

SQLite will allow a foreign key column to bear a `NULL` value and not point to its parent table.  This would allow you to fill in the blanks later, perhaps when you have that information available.