# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_SalesProductTable_SalesMainTable"1

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to insert some values to SalesProductTable and SalesMaintable which are in my database, but when I click the save button, the insert occurrs successfully but it give the following error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint"FK_SalesProductTable_SalesMainTable". The conflict occurred in database "IndusPharmaManagement", table "dbo.SalesMainTable", column 'SalesID'.

The code which share the following two methods is:

```
 private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     MainSaleInsertion();
     individualSaleEntry();
 }
```

Here is my code:

```
    public void individualSaleEntry()
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < CashSalesDgv.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string InsertSaleProductEntry = @"INSERT INTO SalesProductTable (SalesID,ItemName,Price,Qty,TotalAmount,Date) VALUES ('" + CashSalesDgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "','" + CashSalesDgv.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value + "','" + CashSalesDgv.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value + "','" + CashSalesDgv.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value + "','" + CashSalesDgv.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value + "','" + dateTimeSale.Text + "')";
                objDAC.ExecQuery(InsertSaleProductEntry);
                objDAC.infrmUser("Data saved successfully in Product Sales", "Information");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

    public void MainSaleInsertion()
    {
        string InsertSalesMainEntry = @"INSERT INTO SalesMainTable (SalesID,NoOfItems,TotalQty,DiscountPer,DiscountRs, TotalToPay,Paid,Dues,Date) VALUES
                                         ('" + txtInvoiceNo.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtNoOfItems.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtTotalQty.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtDiscountPercentage.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtDiscountRs.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtTotalPayment.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtTotalPayment.Text.Trim() + "',null,'" + dateTimeSale.Text + "')";
        objDAC.ExecQuery(InsertSalesMainEntry);
        objDAC.infrmUser("Data saved successfully in Main Sales", "Information");
    }
```

Comment: the error msg is very specific....Also, SQL injection....

Comment: Among these two tables, which is the table with primary key and which is using it as foreign key? Which method you are calling first and which one next? Can you also share the code which calls these methods ? Which method gives the error/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint - SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965837/insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint-sql-server)

Comment: SalesMainTable has the primary key SalesID while this SalesID is the foreign key in the SalesProductTable

Comment: `MainSaleInsertion` method adds new row to `SalesMainTable` table but the `SalesID` of the new row is not available in `individualSaleEntry` method.  That's why you are getting this error. You are trying to use `CashSalesDgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value` to populate `SalesID` in  `individualSaleEntry` method which might be a not a valid value. So you need to make sure that you have the new SalesID available in `individualSaleEntry` method.