# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint in table insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query that I try to execute:

```
DECLARE @SessionId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID();

INSERT INTO [security].[EventLog] ([Id], [Created], [Updated], [Session],
                                   [IdentityGlobalId], [EventType], [Description])
    SELECT 
        NEWID(), GETUTCDATE(), NULL, @SessionId,
        r.Id, 4 AS [Change], -- RoleRemoved
        'Removed role: ' + CAST(ISNULL(r.Region,'') AS VARCHAR(8)) + ':'+ CAST(ISNULL(r.CustomerNumber,'') AS VARCHAR(8)) + ':' + CAST(ISNULL(r.RoleId,'') AS VARCHAR(8))
    FROM 
        @toRemove r
```

But when I try that, I get the following error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_EventLog_Identities_IdentityGlobalId". The conflict occurred in database "master", table "security.Identities", column 'GlobalId'.

I know that before data can be inserted, the value in the foreign key field must exist in the other table first, in this case the Identities-table. The thing is that when I look into the identities-table, I can see the value right there.

So why do I still get this error?

DDL for the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [security].[Identities]
(
    [GlobalId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
    [Updated] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Identities] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([GlobalId] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [security].[EventLog]
(
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
    [Updated] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
    [Session] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [IdentityGlobalId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [EventType] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Published] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_EventLog] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [security].[EventLog] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_EventLog_Identities_IdentityGlobalId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([IdentityGlobalId]) REFERENCES [security].[Identities] ([GlobalId])
                ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [security].[EventLog] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_EventLog_Identities_IdentityGlobalId]
GO
```

Comment: Please can you share with us the DDL of the EventLog table and the Identities table.

Comment: And check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965837/insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint-sql-server

Comment: @VBoka: Check updted question

Comment: Please can you share also what do you have in toRemove ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing extra details with us(DDL of two tables)
After you shared that I started to test and I realized that your problem is actually with the value that is in your `@toRemove` variable.

You are selecting value from r.Id (r is alias for `@toRemove`) and you are trying to insert that value in the `IdentityGlobalId` column of the table EventLog.

That value does not exist in the table `Identities` in the column `GlobalId` and that is why your FK constraint is throwing error.

I hope this explanation will help you.
I also crated a small example where I create two tables you shared and then I insert one row in the table `Identities`. Then I select random values and value from column `Identities.GlobalId` to insert into table `EventLog`.

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a28b105b7edf7f08742e2b4c780236f5) of that where you can see that `EventLog.IdentityGlobalId` is same as `Identities.GlobalId` and that is the only way your insert will go through - if there is the same value in the `Identities.GlobalId` column as the one you are trying to insert into `EventLog.IdentityGlobalId` column.

Comment: Hi @Bryan , I do not understand, you have 2000+ points and how is it you do not give a feedback to an answer to your question ?