# INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "tblFavoriteTeam_LoginId"

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am getting this error. I was able to publish the Default Data but unable to pass the unit test. Can you please help me?

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "tblFavoriteTeam_LoginId". The conflict occurred in database "TeamJazz.DB", table "dbo.tblLogin", column 'Id'.

My unit test code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void InsertTest()
{
        using (GameEntities dc = new GameEntities())
        {
            tblFavoriteTeam newrow = new tblFavoriteTeam();
            newrow.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            newrow.FavTeamId = Guid.NewGuid();
            newrow.LoginId = Guid.NewGuid();

            dc.tblFavoriteTeams.Add(newrow);
            int result = dc.SaveChanges();

            Assert.IsTrue(result > 0);
        }
}
```

My default data:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LoginId uniqueidentifier;
    DECLARE @FavTeamId uniqueidentifier;

    SELECT @LoginId = Id FROM tblLogin WHERE Email = 'test@gmail.com'
    SELECT @FavTeamId = Id FROM tblTeam WHERE TeamName = 'Packers'

    INSERT INTO tblFavoriteTeam (Id, FavTeamId, LoginId)
    VALUES (NEWID(), @FavTeamId, @LoginId)

    SELECT @LoginId = Id FROM tblLogin WHERE Email = 'test2@gmail.com'
    SELECT @FavTeamId = Id FROM tblTeam WHERE TeamName = 'Cowboys'

    INSERT INTO tblFavoriteTeam (Id, FavTeamId, LoginId)
    VALUES (NEWID(), @FavTeamId, @LoginId)

    SELECT @LoginId = Id FROM tblLogin WHERE Email = 'test3@gmail.com'
    SELECT @FavTeamId = Id FROM tblTeam WHERE TeamName = 'Lions'

    INSERT INTO tblFavoriteTeam (Id, FavTeamId, LoginId)
    VALUES (NEWID(), @FavTeamId, @LoginId)
END
```

Here is the data inside the `FavoriteTeam` table so you know that the default data published:

[image]

Here is the edmx:

[image]

Comment: I think it is because the id you are trying to add does not correspond to an existing element, when you use the Guid.NewGuid () function you are creating an id that does not exist in your database, so there is a conflict in the foreign key of the relationship of your tabalas.

Comment: Hi, to avoid duplication, there's a similar question which has really nice explanations. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2965837/3499361

Answer (score 1):

It's because `tblFavoriteTeams.LoginId` is a foreign key. It needs to exist in `tblLogin`. Your unit test needs to use an existing `LoginId`. Do you have test accounts that you could grab the `LoginId` for instead of creating a new GUID?

You could do something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void InsertTest()
{
    using (GameEntities dc = new GameEntities())
    {
        var login = dc.tblLogin.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LoginId == yourTestUsers.UserId);
        tblFavoriteTeam newrow = new tblFavoriteTeam();
        newrow.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        newrow.FavTeamId = Guid.NewGuid();
        newrow.LoginId = login.LoginId();

        dc.tblFavoriteTeams.Add(newrow);
        int result = dc.SaveChanges();

        Assert.IsTrue(result > 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is 'yourTestUsers.UserId'

Comment: @kroniclogic I was just using that as a descriptive object for what he needs there. Basically, what he needs is a valid user's user id. Depending on their testing environment, maybe the LoginId could be a parameter that is passed in to the test method. There are many options for getting a valid GUID from tblLogin. Cheers!