# My INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUAwp.jpg)

Those are my diagrams - I create procedure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[hasta]
    @Ad nchar(50),
    @Soyadı nvarchar(100),
    @TcKimlik nchar(11), 
    @DogumTarihi varchar(8),
    @TelefonNo nvarchar(11) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
   
    INSERT INTO [dbo].Hastalar ([Ad], [Soyadı], [TcKimlik], [DogumTarihi], [TelefonNo])
    VALUES (@Ad, @Soyadı, @TcKimlik, @DogumTarihi, @TelefonNo)
END
```

After I want add data in Hastalar table, I write

```
exec  hasta  'Emir','Yılmaz','35635993564','1995.11.19','05347331085'
```

but I get this error

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Procedure hasta, Line 13
> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Hastalar_Testler". The conflict occurred in database "hastane", table "dbo.Testler", column 'TestID'. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: The code is clearly SQL Server, so I removed the MySQL tag.

Comment: The error is also telling you the problem. There us a foreign key constraint conflict with the data you are trying to `INSERT`, so the `INSERT` fails.

Comment: sql server m. 2012

Comment: Does this answer your question? [INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint - SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965837/insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your table [dbo].Hastalar, it has a foreign key reference to another table. The way a FK works is it cannot have a value in that column that is not also in the primary key column of the referenced table.

If you have SQL Server Management Studio, open it up and sp_help '[dbo].Hastalar'. See which column that FK is on, and which column of which table it references. You're inserting some bad data.

Answer (score -2):

What part of the error do you not understand?

The message is saying that one of the columns -- "TestId" -- is referring to another table.  And the value being inserted is not already in that table.

You are not explicitly inserting a value for `TestId`, so that value is being set using a default constraint or trigger.  I would suggest that you explicit provide the value in the `insert` -- even if that value is `NULL`.