# SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint - asp.net-core

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-core

I am using a SQL database called as MusicChannel which will hold the new added songs with artists. When I try to add something, it gives me a error saying:

> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Songs__ArtistID__36B12243". The conflict occurred in database "MusicChannel", table "dbo.Artists", column 'ArtistID'.
> The statement has been terminated.

I created the table in order of Artists, MusicTypes and Songs. Songs have 2 FK as ArtistID and MusicTypeID. Artists' PK is ArtistID. MusicTypes' PK is MusicTypeID. Is this happening because the names are the same?

Here is the Model:

```
public IActionResult Insert(NewSongVm formContent)
        {
            if (formContent.MusicTypeID == -1)
            {
                //
            }
            MusicChannelContext ctx = new MusicChannelContext();
            Song song = new Song();
            Artist artist = new Artist();
            song.SongID = formContent.SongID;
            song.SongName = formContent.SongName;
            song.SongLength = formContent.SongLength;
            song.SongLink = formContent.SongLink;
            song.MusicTypeID = formContent.MusicTypeID;
            song.ArtistID = formContent.ArtistID;
            artist.ArtistID = formContent.ArtistID;
            artist.ArtistName = formContent.ArtistName;
            ctx.Artists.Add(artist);
            ctx.Songs.Add(song);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
            return View();
        }
 
//context:

 public class MusicChannelContext:DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("server=.;database=MusicChannel;trusted_connection=true;");  
        }
        public DbSet<Song> Songs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MusicType> MusicTypes { get; set; }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: What about the error don't you understand? It's telling you the problem here. if you explain what confuses you, we can try to elaborate on the areas that confuse you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint - SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965837/insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint-sql-server)

Comment: Please check out the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965837/insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint-sql-server).This might resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save changes in `Artist` table, `Add` command does not create a record in the database.

Another solution in drop FK constraint from table in database, then you can create records in any orders you want.

Check the following sample:

```cs
MusicChannelContext ctx = new MusicChannelContext();
Artist artist = new Artist();
artist.ArtistID = formContent.ArtistID;
artist.ArtistName = formContent.ArtistName;
ctx.Artists.Add(artist);
ctx.SaveChanges();

Song song = new Song();
song.SongID = formContent.SongID;
song.SongName = formContent.SongName;
song.SongLength = formContent.SongLength;
song.SongLink = formContent.SongLink;
song.MusicTypeID = formContent.MusicTypeID;
song.ArtistID = formContent.ArtistID;

ctx.Songs.Add(song);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```