Get Category Id from table to create on other table in ASP.NET Core
I want to insert data, a food with its category, from 2 tables into database.
This is my method that creates the food including name, image. But it also has a category with another table that is Food Category, I want to add new food to table with its category, but in get method, I can not get the Category Id from list.
This is my method:
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateFoodByAdmin(CreateFoodViewModel createFoodViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    { 
        var result = await _foodService.CreateFoodByAdmin(createFoodViewModel);

        switch (result)
        {
            case CreateFoodResult.FoodIsExist:
                await GetFoodCategory();
                ModelState.AddModelError("FoodTitle", "Food Title exists");
                return View(createFoodViewModel);

            case CreateFoodResult.NotFound:
                return RedirectToAction("NotFound");

            case CreateFoodResult.Success:
                return RedirectToAction("FoodList");
        }
    }

    await GetFoodCategory();

    return View(createFoodViewModel);
}

And in the view, I listed them with a for each too:
<label >Food Category Lis</label>

<ul>
    <span asp-validation-for="FoodCategoryId"></span>

    @foreach (var foodCat in foodCategory)
    {
        <li>
            <input class="form-check-input" name="FoodSelectedCategories" type="checkbox" value="@foodCat.FoodCategoryId" id="categoryCheckbox">
@foodCat.FoodCategoryTitle
        </li>
    }
</ul>

I also have a method to get all categories name and pass it to view with view data:
List<FoodCategoryViewModel> foodCategory = ViewData["FoodCategory"] as List<FoodCategoryViewModel>;

With all that after breakpoint I receive all data except FoodCategoryId. Why?
this is Update:
I create models first , and use from view model.
I add this property to "CreateFoodViewModel"
     public List<int> FoodCategoryId { get; set; }

and want after add food and its category , I add selectedfoodcategory to that Table
I Get food category by this method and pass it by viewdata to view:
    public async Task GetFoodCategory()
    {
        var foodCategory = await _foodService.GetAllFoodCategory();
        ViewData["FoodCategory"] = foodCategory;
    }


new update:
I change it as you said and now it is ok and I get FoodCategoryId from entrance , but I have error in add it to FoodSelectedCategory and It does not add to db;
SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_FoodSelectedCategories_FoodCategories_FoodCategoryId". The conflict occurred in database "EvSef_db", table "dbo.FoodCategories", column 'FoodCategoryId'.

this is my diagram:
enter image description here
enter image description here
this is my method to add food selected category :
   public async Task AddFoodCategoryToFoodList(int foodId, List<int> foodCategoryId)

{
if (!foodCategoryId.Any()) return;
foreach (var foodCat in foodCategoryId)
{
FoodSelectedCategory x = new FoodSelectedCategory()
{
FoodId = foodId,
FoodCategoryId = foodCat,
RegisterDate = DateTime.Now,
       };
       await _foodRepository.AddFoodCategoryToFood(x);
       await _foodRepository.SaveChanges();
   }


Could you share your model FoodCategoryViewModel and  CreateFoodViewModel?

If you use   public List<int> FoodCategoryId { get; set; }, have a try like: name="FoodCategoryId[@i]"

@QingGuo Thanks It s ok now and I got the Id but I have other error, Update queastion

"You must insert data into the parent table, containing the primary key, before attempting to insert data into the foreign key." Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965837/insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint-sql-server

yes first I insert it to parent table and food insert to Food table correctly , but after that it can not add to second table : FoodCategoryselected. Update q. with all method

@QingGuo I check alot i have not conflict on my diagram , why I see this conflict? this error is relevant to  my diagram or code?


I receive all data except FoodCategoryId. Why?

The name atrribute should be the same as FoodCategoryId, then we can bind the FoodCategoryId to the property in CreateFoodViewModel.
Option 1 :
You can try to add the below line into your CreateFoodViewModel:
 public List<FoodCategoryViewModel> FoodCategoryViewModel { get;set;}

Then modify the code like:
 <label>Food Category Lis</label>

    <ul>
        <span asp-validation-for="FoodCategoryId"></span>
        @for (var i = 0; i < foodCategory.Count; i++)
        {
            <li>
                <input class="form-check-input" name="FoodCategoryViewModel[@i].FoodCategoryId" type="checkbox" value="@foodCategory[@i].FoodCategoryId" id="categoryCheckbox">
                @foodCategory[@i].FoodCategoryTitle
            </li>
        }
        
    </ul>

result:

Option 2:
Add below code in the CreateFoodViewModel:
public List<string> FoodSelectedCategories { get; set; }

Then modify the code like:
 @for (var i = 0; i < foodCategory.Count; i++)
  {
      <li>
          <input class="form-check-input" name="FoodSelectedCategories[@i]" type="checkbox" value="@foodCategory[@i].FoodCategoryId" id="categoryCheckbox">
          @foodCategory[@i].FoodCategoryTitle
      </li>
  }

result:

